# Ruby recursion: getting some weird output.!

Tags: ruby, recursion

```
class Array
  def total_zeros index = entries.length-1, total = 0
    p "total entries = #{entries.length}"
    i = 0
    if index >= 0
      p "in if block"
      i = i+1
      total_zeros index-1, total
    end
    p "hello #{i}"
  end
end

a = [0,1,2]
p a.total_zeros
```

This is my sample output:

```
"total entries = 3"
"in if block"
"total entries = 3"
"in if block"
"total entries = 3"
"in if block"
"total entries = 3"
"hello 0"
"hello 1"
"hello 1"
"hello 1"
nil
```

Can anybody please help me to understand this code? I am not able to understand why the last line "hello" is printed four times. It is a recursion and "hello" should be printed only once having `i` equal to 4.

Comment: entries will give you the values in array. i think its ruby variable.

Comment: OK..It is a method... I see :)

Comment: Do you just want to count the total number of `0` 's  in an array ?

Comment: no i want to understand the how ruby is executing this code and why am i getting that output.!

Comment: Did you write this or did you find it somewhere and you are trying to understand it?

Comment: how does that mattter ?,anyway i haven't written it i am only trying to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

"hello" is printed 4 times because you call it once outside, then 3 more times due to recursion. All the function calls have to exit, so you get a print of hello when it does.

As to why `i` does not have the value 4 - The scope of `i` is limited to the method. The method gets called 4 times and 4 different integers get initialised to zero and incremented by one.

Comment: 4 different integers get initialized to zero?  Integers are immediate values and as such are never initialized.